# How to stop execution of function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to stop execution of function in javascript?

Please see below code:

```
   if(m=='')
    {
    alert("novalue");
    getDate().stopPropagation();
    }
```

I want that `if(m==null)` the `getDate()` should not get executed.

How this can get achieved in javascript?

Comment: ...use a nested `if`?

Comment: use `===` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 1):

did you changed the question?

```
if (m==='') {
    ...
}
```

`===` matches the value and the type

Comment: actually i go stuck here "getDate().stopPropagation();"

Comment: That's because `stopPropagation()` is not a method of the `Date` object. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the if condition as below

```
    if(m=='' && m !== null) {

    }
```

This may help you.